# Manipulating variables using globals() in python

Tags: python, variables, parameter-passing, global

I wanted to have the option to pass my arguments to a function in a concise manner. So instead of passing all arguments directly, I include them  as parameters function definiton and pass all such arguments as `Common_Args`. Then I do the following

```py
       for key, value in Common_args.items():
            if key in locals():
                globals()[key] = value
```

Here is the problem. Even though the control goes inside the if condition(checked with debugger), the parameter's value do not change, but it should, right?
[Guides](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-globals-function/#:%7E:text=Python%20%E2%80%93%20globals()%20function,-View%20Discussion&text=globals()%20function%20in%20Python,%2C%20methods%2C%20classes%2C%20et)  have confirmed that this should work, and if I run single statements in my debugger, the value of the variable does change.

---

My function definition in more detail is

```py
def plotLFPData1Channel(plotHandles=None, channelString="", stimulus_list=None, folderName=None, analysisType=None,
                        timeVals=None, plotColor=None, blRange=None, stRange=None, referenceChannelString=None,
                        badTrialNameStr=None, useCommonBadTrialsFlag=None ,*,Common_args=None):
    # first we have to unpack common args
    if Common_args is not None:
        for key, value in Common_args.items():
            if key in locals():
                globals()[key] = value
```

and I call the function like so

```py
result=plotLFPData1Channel(plotHandles=ax.flatten(), channelString=analogChannelString, stimulus_list=stimValsToUse,analysisType=analysisType,Common_args=commonArgs)
```

with `commonArgs={"folderName":folderName , "timeVals":timeVals, "plotColor":plotColor, "blRange":blRange, "stRange":stRange, "referenceChannelString":referenceChannelString,                     "badTrialNameStr":badTrialNameStr, "useCommonBadTrialsFlag":useCommonBadTrialsFlag}`

Comment: You are creating/modifying a *global* variable with the same name as the local one, but the local one keeps its value, so I don't see anything surprising here. The whole thing, though, is a bit... strange. Why not simply call your function with `plot...(**commonArgs)`??

Comment: Even with locals()[key]=value there is no change.  How do I use **kwargs to achieve this? Basically common Args are the arguments that generally don't change between runs, so I don't want the function call to look big .

Comment: [The doc for locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) explicitely states:"The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter." - so don't try that, it doesn't work. For the rest, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters ...